# How to deploy pure javascript apps (on s3)?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, deployment, amazon-s3

My app is pure clientside javascript, html and images (Backbone.js, require.js, Handlebars). There is now serverside code (in fact it talks to a sinatra-app, but this is not part of my deployment).

My goal is to deploy it on a good static host (like s3). I'm familiar with capistrano but i wanted to ask if there are common ways for such standalone clientside apps. It should support multistage environments and allow me to create hooks within the process (e.g. to optimize with r.js).